# Old school horror/sci-fi illustrated anthology

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror, childrens-novel

I randomly remembered an old horror story anthology I read when I was younger, the book was at the local Toronto Public Library. I can remember a couple of stories from it.

One was about a boy whose uncle invented a machine that allowed a human to levitate. I remember the machine being unpleasant/painful to experience, but the longer a human can endure the higher they can float. They encounter a "*cloud monster*" that look sort of like a floating squid, which the uncle scares away with a sort of weaponized laser-pointer. Later, the boy hears the machine had exploded and killed they uncle, and he wonders if the creature somehow was responsible.

There was another one about a girl who gets a box in the mail to watch for a neighbour. The neighbour is suspected by the local children of being a witch, despite warnings to the contrary, the girl opens the box and sees a small, dry shriveled thing she flings away in horror. The creature grows in the dark and eventually the witch shuts her in a room with it saying she "shouldn't have opened the box", the creature reaches for her while saying "hello INSERT NAME HERE". The monster in question was sort of purple, with yellow fangs and an almost boar like head and tubes/spines on it's back.

The third story involved a bob-cat being brought along on a space voyage, and finding a sort of alien tiger, only longer and with one horn that when angry started inhaling air and growing, the entire story was from the bob-cats perspective. They all were illustrated with a very old school style

I think there was another story about a boy who goes on a spaceship to escape a family vampire curse, he winds up on an alien planet whose inhabitants, looking slightly like kangaroos, have a blood letting/drinking ritual involving their long eared cattle-esque heard beasts, but that might be from unrelated collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The others are from the book "[Baleful Beasts and Eerie Creatures](http://the-haunted-closet.blogspot.com/2008/07/rest-of-baleful-beasts-and-eerie.html)". For some reason the stories popped into my head a while back.

Reviews

> TIGGER by A.M. Lightner
>
> Tigger is the name of the sentient cat that serves as scout and guard, of sorts, for a team of astronauts exploring an alien world somewhere in the future.
>
> [image: Tigger image from the book]
>
> Tigger's the one on the left, a super-evolved descendent of the modern housecat. The story is told first-person, from his perspective.
>
> Tigger and his human partner Ellie encounter a fearsome alien while searching for plantlife.

....

> THE NIGHT CREATURE by Richard R. Smith
>
> In the second science-fiction story in this collection, a scientist lets his 12-year old nephew in on a secret device he's developed that enables levitation. They both take it for a test ride in the night sky, only to be attacked by a mysterious octopus-like flying "night creature."

And "[Nightmare in a Box](http://the-haunted-closet.blogspot.com/2008/07/nightmare-in-box.html)"

> The young girl is Tracy Ann Stuart. The old woman is Miss Lulu Cranshaw...or as she's known in the neighborhood, "Creepy" Cranshaw. Tracy suspects she's a witch.
>
> Earlier that day Tracy received delivery of a parcel for Miss Cranshaw, who wasn't at home. Her parents are away as well, possibly overnight. Tracy is to hold onto the package until Miss Cranshaw returns.
>
> Of course this wouldn't be a horror story if her curiosity didn't get the better of her. She carefully opens the little box...

Answer (score 2):

You've confirmed that the last story was "[A Thirst for Blood](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?68083)" by Arthur Toffee, but unfortunately, that story seems to have only been recorded in one anthology, [*More Science Fiction Tales: Crystal Creatures, Bird-Things & Other Weirdies*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?22831), the contents of which do not match up to your other stories.

Summary from [here](http://the-haunted-closet.blogspot.com/2013/07/more-science-fiction-tales-roger-elwood.html):

> **A Thirst For Blood** (Arthur Tofte), a story of vampires and interplanetary adventure set in the year 2040, opens with a boy being forced to carry out the grim ritual of decapitating the corpse of his father to cancel a vampiric curse.